# Transform article XML to HTML with XSL: Keywords loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform article XML to HTML, but the keywords in other languages does not show up. Attached the xml file and xsl file.

**XML**
This is the abstract in XML. Notice there are two tags abstract and trans-abstract and they have keywords

```
            <abstract>
            <title>RESUMEN</title>
            <p>
                <italic>En este artículo se presenta la importancia que le da Hannah Arendt al relato histórico y ficticio como vía para la reflexión ética y política. </italic>
            </p>
        </abstract>
        <trans-abstract xml:lang="en">
            <title>ABSTRACT</title>
            <p>
                <italic>This article presents the importance given by Hannah Arendt to historical and fictional stories as a way for ethical and political reflection.</italic>
            </p>
        </trans-abstract>

        <kwd-group xml:lang="es">
            <title>Palabras clave:</title>
            <kwd>Narración</kwd>
            <kwd>política</kwd>
            <kwd>acción</kwd>
            <kwd>identidad</kwd>
            <kwd>memoria</kwd>
            <kwd>juicio</kwd>
        </kwd-group>
        <kwd-group xml:lang="en">
            <title>Keywords:</title>
            <kwd>Narration</kwd>
            <kwd>politics</kwd>
            <kwd>action</kwd>
            <kwd>identity</kwd>
            <kwd>memory</kwd>
            <kwd>judgement</kwd>
        </kwd-group>
```

**XSL**
Now this is XSL file and it has two loops for abstract(language original) and other for translated-abstract. The abstract works but the other one not. Maybe it is the conditional o the loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="abstract">
      <!-- title in left column, content (paras, secs) in right -->
      <div class="metadata two-column table">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="text-align: right">
            <h4 class="callout-title">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="title/node()"/>
              <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(string(title)))">
                <span class="generated">
                  <xsl:if test="self::trans-abstract">Translated </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:text>Abstract</xsl:text>
                </span>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="text-align: right">
            <h4 class="callout-title">
              <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang)))">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../kwd-group[@xml:lang=/article/@xml:lang]/title/node()"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            <h4 class="callout-title">
              <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang)))">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../kwd-group[@xml:lang=/article/@xml:lang]/kwd/node()"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- title in left column, content (paras, secs) in right -->
    <xsl:for-each select="trans-abstract ">
      <!-- title in left column, content (paras, secs) in right -->
      <div class="metadata two-column table">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="text-align: right">
            <h4 class="callout-title">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="title/node()"/>
              <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(string(title)))">
                <span class="generated">
                  <xsl:if test="self::trans-abstract">Translated </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:text>Abstract</xsl:text>
                </span>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="text-align: right">
            <h4 class="callout-title">
            <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang))"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="/article/front/article-meta/kwd-group">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>

              <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang))">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../kwd-group[@xml:lang=normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang))]/title/node()"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            <h4 class="callout-title">

              <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(attribute::xml:lang))">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../kwd-group[@xml:lang=attribute::xml:lang]/kwd/node()"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This is the result
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL0rm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `<xsl:for-each select="trans-abstract ">`, if you want to navigate to the `kwd-group` of the same language use `../kwd-group[lang(current()/@xml:lang)]`.